# Two-shot generator

Tags: python, iterator, generator

How can you make a 2-shot generator in python?

My attempt (doesn't work):

```
>>> def g():
...     try:
...         yield 1
...         raise StopIteration('Shot 1 exhausted')
...     finally:
...         yield 2
...         # 'Shot 2 exhausted'
...         
>>> x = g()
>>> list(x), list(x)
([1, 2], [])
# expected output ([1], [2])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [iterator protocol](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types) specifically forbids this:

> The intention of the protocol is that once an iterator’s `next()` method
>   raises `StopIteration`, it will continue to do so on subsequent calls.
>   Implementations that do not obey this property are deemed broken.

For this reason, the generator syntax does not offer a way to make a 2-shot iterator.

If you really want to do it anyway, you can't use a generator:

```
class BrokenIterator(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.callcount = 0
    def __iter__(self):
        return self
    def next(self):
        self.callcount += 1
        if self.callcount == 1:
            return 1
        elif self.callcount == 3:
            return 2
        else:
            raise StopIteration
```

Comment: Nothing in his code stopped raising `StopIteration` on subsequent calls to `next()`...

Comment: With this I get `TypeError: iter() returned non-iterator of type 'BrokenIterator'`.  Anyway, I want to try and do it with `yield`

Comment: @wim: Works for me. Are you on Python 3? If so, the `next` method will have to be changed to `__next__`. If you want to try to do it with `yield`, go ahead, but you'll probably have to cheat. For example, make an object whose `__iter__` method is a generator that modifies the object's state - but then the object isn't an iterator, just a 2-shot iterable.

Comment: Yes, python 3!  I know how to do with a custom class, but when I tried to do it with a generator function, using yield and maintain state by using a mutable default argument, it didn't work  :)

Comment: @metatoaster: His use case specifically requires his generator to yield 1, raise StopIteration, yield 2, then raise StopIteration again.

Comment: @user2357112 I saw the logic provided, with the lack of explanation of what constitute a 2-shot generator, I saw that as a generator that is to return two values.